# Not able to get store in sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2, undefined, store

I has define store in sencha touch as follow:

store.js

```
  Ext.define('bluebutton.store.BlueButton.Testing', {
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
    requires: [
              'bluebutton.model.BlueButton.Testing'
    ],
    config: {
        storeId: 'testingstore',
        model: 'bluebutton.model.BlueButton.Testing'
    }
});
```

Model.js

```
    Ext.define('bluebutton.model.BlueButton.Testing', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    requires: [
             'Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage'
    ],

    config: {
        fields: [
            { name: 'first', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'second', type: 'string' }
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'localstorage',
            id: '_codeAnalyzerLocalStorage'
        }
    }
});
```

I need to call getStore()

```
    Ext.define('bluebutton.view.BlueButton.testing', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype: 'testing',
       requires: [

    'bluebutton.view.BlueButton.TransactionList',
    'bluebutton.view.BlueButton.MemberPopUp',
     'bluebutton.view.BlueButton.MemberDetail',
     'bluebutton.store.BlueButton.MemberList',

     'bluebutton.model.BlueButton.Testing',
     'bluebutton.store.BlueButton.Testing'




    ],

    config: {
     id:'register',
        items :[

              {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'name',
                    label: 'Name'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'emailfield',
                    name: 'email',
                    label: 'Email'
                },



                {

                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Test Local',
                     handler: function(button) {


                       var test =   Ext.getCmp('testingstore').getStore();   

                       alert(test);





                       }




                },









        ],


   }

});
```

But I get this error

```
getStore is undefined
```

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add your store in app.js

you have to put your store in **stores** array,because of the sencha bug for  storeId Referencing(as I know , js loading order of the app scripts),so if you want to use 
storeId,put your store in app.js.

Ext.application({

```
name : 'bluebutton',

views : [ 'BlueButton.Testing', ],  

stores : [ 'BlueButton.Testing', ], //this is the key


models : [ 'BlueButton.Testing', ], 

launch : function() {
    Ext.create('bluebutton.view.BlueButton.Testing');
}
```

});

Answer (score 5):

I tried it with following code and it works without a problem!

store:

```
Ext.define('bluebutton.store.BlueButton.Testing', {
    extend : "Ext.data.Store",
    requires : [ 'bluebutton.model.BlueButton.Testing' ],
    config : {
        storeId : 'testingstore',
        model : 'bluebutton.model.BlueButton.Testing'
    }
});
```

model:

```
Ext.define('bluebutton.model.BlueButton.Testing', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    requires : ['Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage'],
    config : {
        fields : [{
                    name : 'first',
                    type : 'string'
                }, {
                    name : 'second',
                    type : 'string'
                }],
        proxy : {
            type : 'localstorage',
            id : '_codeAnalyzerLocalStorage'
        }
    }
});
```

view:

```
Ext.define('bluebutton.view.BlueButton.Testing', {
        extend : 'Ext.form.Panel',
        xtype : 'testing',
        config : {
            fullscreen : true,
            id : 'register',
            items : [{
                        xtype : 'textfield',
                        name : 'name',
                        label : 'Name'
                    }, {
                        xtype : 'emailfield',
                        name : 'email',
                        label : 'Email'
                    }, {
                        xtype : 'button',
                        text : 'Test Local',
                        handler : function(button) {
                            var test = Ext.getStore('testingstore');
                            console.log(test);
                        }
                    }]
        }
    });
```

app.js:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled : true,
});

Ext.application({

    name : 'bluebutton',

    views : [ 'BlueButton.Testing', ],  
    stores : [ 'BlueButton.Testing', ], 
    models : [ 'BlueButton.Testing', ], 

    launch : function() {
        Ext.create('bluebutton.view.BlueButton.Testing');
    }

});
```

The console logs me the store after pushing the button.

But I think it would be a nicer code, when you put the button action in the controller, not the view!

```
button config:
    {
        xtype : 'button',
        text : 'Test Local',
        action : 'buttonTest'

    }
```

controller:

```
Ext.define('bluebutton.controller.BlueButton.Testing', {
    extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config : {
        control : {
            'button[action="buttonTest"]' : {
                tap : 'testButtonTap'
            }
        }
    },
    testButtonTap : function() {
        var test = Ext.getStore('testingstore');
        console.log(test);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the store with

```
var test =   Ext.getStore('testingstore');
```

Sencha Touch API: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext-method-getStore

Comment: hi, i try adi. also get undefined

Comment: Did you refer in app.js to your store? store: ['BlueButton.Testing']

Comment: hi, i adi put in my app.js but still get this error.Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getStore' of undefined